# Render all items of the main menu on one page

Tags: routes

i am building a overview page of my website.
My Main Menu has the following structure:

MenuItem1

- submenuitem1
- submenuitem2
- submenuitemn

MenuItem2

- submenuitem1
- submenuitem2
- submenuitemn

MenuItem3

- submenuitem1
- submenuitem2
- submenuitemn

MenuItem4

- submenuitem1
- submenuitem2
- submenuitemn

I want to render each Menuitem with his submenuitems in a different div and add an image to it.
I know i can work with the menu block module. But because we have the domain access module running and lots of domains, it has to be a coded solution. Each domain has his own main menu and should build dynamically the overview.

I managed to  output the whole main menu expandend with this code:

```
$main_menu_tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
$main_menu_expanded = menu_tree_output($main_menu_tree);
print render($main_menu_expanded);
```

How can i accomplish my mission ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can try with dhtml menu.

1. download dhtml module
   http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu
2. Configure menu setting
   admin/config/user-interface/dhtml_menu

Comment: unfortunaly that is not what i am searching for.